# Mutable 2d Vector classs

Tags: python, python-3.x, coordinate-system

I create a 2dVector class to use a position coordinates in a pygame application and maybe in the future as part of a physics engine. Does this implementation has any huge downsides? Is the type hinting ok?

```
import math
import random
from numbers import Real
from typing import Union, Sequence, cast

VectorType = Sequence[Real]


class Vector(VectorType):
    x: Real
    y: Real
    rotation: Real
    magnitude: Real

    def __init__(self, x: Union[VectorType, Real], y: Real = None) -> None:
        if y is None:
            x, y = cast(VectorType, x)
        self.x, self.y = cast(Real, x), y

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}{self.x, self.y}"

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return 2

    def __getitem__(self, i: int) -> Real:
        return (self.x, self.y)[i]

    def __add__(self, other: VectorType):
        return Vector(self.x + other[0], self.y + other[1])

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x + other[0], self.y + other[1])

    def __iadd__(self, other: VectorType):
        self.x += other[0]
        self.y += other[1]
        return self

    def __sub__(self, other: VectorType):
        return Vector(self.x - other[0], self.y - other[1])

    def __rsub__(self, other: VectorType):
        return Vector(other[0] - self.x, other[1] - self.y)

    def __isub__(self, other: VectorType):
        self.x -= other[0]
        self.y -= other[1]
        return self

    def __mul__(self, other: Real) -> Vector:
        return Vector(self.x * other, self.y * other)

    def __rmul__(self, other: Real):
        return Vector(self.x * other, self.y * other)

    def __matmul__(self, other: VectorType):
        return Vector(self.x * other[0], self.y * other[1])

    def __rmatmul__(self, other):
        return Vector(other[0] * self.x, other[1] * self.y)

    def __truediv__(self, other: Union[VectorType, Real]) -> Vector:
        if isinstance(other, Sequence):
            return Vector(self.x / other[0], self.y / other[1])
        return Vector(self.x / other, self.y / other)

    def __rtruediv__(self, other: VectorType) -> Vector:
        self.x /= other
        self.y /= other
        return self

    def __round__(self, n=None) -> Vector:
        return Vector(round(self.x, n), round(self.x, n))

    def change_rotation(self, rotation: float) -> Vector:
        v = Vector(self.x, self.y)
        v.rotation += rotation
        return v

    @classmethod
    def random(cls, x_range=(0, 1), y_range=(0, 1)):
        return cls(random.uniform(*x_range), random.uniform(*y_range))

    @classmethod
    def from_polar(cls, rotation: Real, magnitude: Real):
        return Vector(math.cos(rotation) * magnitude, math.sin(rotation) * magnitude)

    def normalize(self):
        f = self.magnitude
        self.x *= f
        self.y *= f
        return self

    @property
    def magnitude(self) -> Real:
        return (self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y) ** 0.5

    @magnitude.setter
    def magnitude(self, value: Real):
        f = value / self.magnitude
        self.x *= f
        self.y *= f

    @property
    def rotation(self):
        return math.atan2(self.x, self.y)

    @rotation.setter
    def rotation(self, value):
        m = self.magnitude
        self.x = math.sin(value)
        self.y = math.cos(value)
        self.magnitude = m

    @property
    def rounded(self):
        return round(self.x), round(self.y)
```

[Here is the code on github](https://github.com/MegaIng1/game-engine/blob/master/vector.py) (with a few additions)

Comment: `Vector(round(self.x, n), round(self.x, n))` typo for `Vector(round(self.x, n), round(self.y, n))` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, glad you pointed that out. Would have been a pretty hard to catch bug.

Comment: also in `rotation` you're assigning m to the magnitude, then assign it the other way round: it achieves nothing

Comment: pretty nice code, that said

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes it does. It will set `self.x` and `self.y` to the correct values. (Multiply them with magnitude) , because `self.magnitude = m` invokes the property setter.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre But I could also directly multiply with m, which would maybe make the purpose more clear.

Comment: oh you're right, this property stuff is confusing me := don't forget to edit the `round` function so it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There are no docstrings.
2. I would suggest reconsidering the mutability of the vectors. The advantages of mutability are:

   a. You get to reuse the original storage for the original vector when you make a change, avoiding a couple of memory management operations.

   b. You save a couple of characters when writing some update operations, for example you can write `v.normalize()` instead of, say, `v = v.normalized()`.

   But the disadvantage of mutability is that it is harder to reason about operations. If you see a function that takes some vectors, let's say

   ```
   def collide(p: VectorType, q: VectorType, r: Real) -> Bool:
       "Return True if p and q are separated by no more than r."
   ```

   is it safe to pass `p=sprite.position`, or do you need to make a copy? With mutability, then for all you know, the function is implemented like this:

   ```
   p -= q
   return p.magnitude <= r
   ```

   So in a world where vectors are mutable, you have to worry about this possibility, and perhaps document for each function which arguments get mutated and which don't. If vectors are immutable, then all this is unnecessary and reasoning about the behaviour of code is easier.

   Immutability would avoid the need to implement the `__iadd__` and `__isub__` methods. Also, you could inherit from `tuple` and save some memory. See [this vector class on github](https://github.com/gareth-rees/geometry/blob/master/vector.py) for some implementation ideas.
3. The `__truediv__` method has different behaviour based on the type of the argument. This is inconsistent with the behaviour of `__mul__` and `__rmul__` and `__rtruediv__`, none of which have this behaviour. Also, dispatching based on the type makes it harder to read and reason about code. If you know that `v` is a vector and then you read the expression `v / a`, you can't immediately deduce that `a` must be a scalar as you could in the case of `v * a`.

   I guess that you added the variant operation because of some use case. But nonetheless I would recommend giving the variant operation a different method name, for example `scaled`.
4. In `__radd__` the operations should be reversed, with the other values on the left (just in case they have unusual implementations of `__add__` method):

   ```
   def __radd__(self, other):
       return Vector(other[0] + self.x, other[1] + self.y)
   ```

   Similarly for `__rmul__`.
5. There's no checking that the other vector has the right length. There's nothing stopping me from writing:

   ```
   Vector(1, 2) + [3, 4, 5]
   ```

   which ought to be an error.
6. In `__repr__` I suggest writing `type(self)` rather than `self.__class__`, just as you would write `len(s)` rather than `s.__len__()`.
7. In `from_polar` you should call `cls` rather than `Vector`, to support subclasses.
8. `normalize` has the operations the wrong way round: you need to divide by the magnitude, not multiply. But it would be simpler to write `self.magnitude = 1`.
9. In `magnitude` it would be clearer to call the argument `length` or `magnitude` rather than `value`.
10. In `magnitude`, consider writing `math.hypot(self.x, self.y)`.
11. In `rotation` it would be clearer to call the argument `theta` or `angle` rather than `value`.

Comment: Do you think I need to add docstrings to all methods? Even `__add__` or `__getitem__`?

Comment: I wouldn't write docstrings for methods that are already adequately documented in the [Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). Unless there's something special or surprising about your implementation.

Comment: Added suggestion 1 and 4-11 to [github](https://github.com/MegaIng1/game-engine/blob/master/vector.py). To 2: I want to keep the mutability. It is quite useful. To 3: I want to keep the simple division by a scalar or a vector. I no it is a mess, I already thoughtabout overwriting `__divmod__` and returning `result, None`, but that is better in my opinion. Any ideas?

Comment: I mean overwriting `__divmod__` isn't better

Comment: The [specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__divmod__) for `__divmod__` says: "The `__divmod__` method should be the equivalent to using `__floordiv__` and `__mod__`; it should not be related to `__truediv__`." So overriding this method with something related to `__truediv__` has the potential to lead to confusion and error. I suggest using another method name, for example `scaled` or `scaled_down`.