# Mutable 2d Rect class

Tags: python, python-3.x, coordinate-system, collision

So I wrote a 2d rectangle class for use in a 2d pygame based game engine. It uses the vector class from [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193295/mutable-2d-vector-classs), so if you want to test, you need that code too. I want to ask: Does this implementation has any huge downsides? Is the type hinting ok? Do I have any typos?

```
from numbers import Real
from typing import Sequence, Tuple

from vector import Vector, VectorType

RectType = Sequence[VectorType]

class Rect(RectType):
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return 2

    def __getitem__(self, i: int) -> Vector:
        if i == 0:
            return self.pos1
        else:
            return self.pos2

    pos1: Vector
    pos2: Vector

    def __init__(self, pos1: VectorType, pos2: VectorType):
        x1, x2 = sorted((pos1[0], pos2[0]))
        y1, y2 = sorted((pos1[1], pos2[1]))
        self.pos1 = Vector(x1, y1)
        self.pos2 = Vector(x2, y2)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}{(self.pos1, self.pos2)}"

    @classmethod
    def from_xywh(cls, xy: VectorType, wh: VectorType):
        return Rect(Vector(xy), Vector(xy) + Vector(wh))

    def scale_wh(self, scale: VectorType) -> Rect:
        return Rect((self.pos1.x * scale[0], self.pos1.y * scale[1]), (self.pos2.x * scale[0], self.pos2.y * scale[1]))

    def collide_point(self, pos: VectorType):
        return self.pos1.x <= pos[0] <= self.pos2[1] and self.pos1.y <= pos[1] <= self.pos2.y

    def collide_rect(self, other: Rect):
        return any(self.collide_point(p) for p in (other.top_left, other.top_right, other.bottom_left, other.bottom_right)) or \
               any(other.collide_point(p) for p in (self.top_left, self.top_right, self.bottom_left, self.bottom_right))

    def relative_rect(self, parent: Rect) -> Rect:
        p1 = self.pos1 - parent.pos1
        p1 = Vector(p1.x / parent.w, p1.y / parent.h)
        p2 = self.pos2 - parent.pos1
        p2 = Vector(p2.x / parent.w, p2.y / parent.h)
        return self.__class__(p1, p2)

    def relative_point(self, point: VectorType) -> Vector:
        return (point - self.pos1) / self.wh

    @property
    def xywh(self):
        return self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height

    @property
    def width(self):
        return abs(self.pos1.x - self.pos2.x)

    w = width

    @property
    def height(self):
        return abs(self.pos1.y - self.pos2.y)

    h = height

    @property
    def size(self):
        return Vector(self.w, self.h)

    wh: Vector = size

    @property
    def left(self) -> float:
        return self.pos1.x

    @left.setter
    def left(self, value: float):
        self.pos1.x = value

    @property
    def right(self):
        return self.pos2.x

    @right.setter
    def right(self, value):
        self.pos2.x = value

    @property
    def top(self):
        return self.pos1.y

    @top.setter
    def top(self, value):
        self.pos1.y = value

    @property
    def bottom(self):
        return self.pos2.y

    @bottom.setter
    def bottom(self, value):
        self.pos2.y = value

    @property
    def top_left(self) -> Vector:
        return self.pos1

    @top_left.setter
    def top_left(self, value: Vector):
        self.pos1 = value

    xy: Vector = top_left

    @property
    def bottom_right(self) -> Vector:
        return self.pos2

    @bottom_right.setter
    def bottom_right(self, value: Vector):
        self.pos2 = value

    @property
    def top_right(self) -> Vector:
        return Vector(self.pos2.x, self.pos1.y)

    @top_right.setter
    def top_right(self, value: Vector):
        self.pos2.x, self.pos1.y = value

    @property
    def bottom_left(self) -> Vector:
        return Vector(self.pos1.x, self.pos2.y)

    @bottom_left.setter
    def bottom_left(self, value: VectorType):
        self.pos1.x, self.pos2.y = value

    @property
    def center(self) -> Vector:
        return Vector(self.pos1.x + self.w / 2, self.pos1.y + self.h / 2)

    @property
    def normalized(self):
        x1, x2 = sorted((self.pos1.x, self.pos2.x))
        y1, y2 = sorted((self.pos1.y, self.pos2.y))
        return Rect((x1, y1), (x2, y2))
```

[Here is the code on github](https://github.com/MegaIng1/game-engine/blob/master/rect.py) (with a few additions)

Comment: Have you reviewed your code and tested it for typos yourself?

Comment: @Hosch250 Yes, and I didn't find any. But maybe I just didn't look close enough.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> return abs(self.pos1.x - self.pos2.x)
> ```

The `abs` is unnecessary since you've already sorted the coordinates.

I'm not sure using `Vector` for both absolute positions and relative sizes is the best practice. But in any event, you're missing the type hinting in

> ```
> def size(self):
> ```

We also see a problem with:

> ```
> @left.setter
>     def left(self, value: float):
>         self.pos1.x = value
> ```

in that it does not handle the case where the "left" is set to something greater than the right. It should either raise, or switch the coordinates. Similar with the other property setters.

Comment: How would you go about solving the typehint problem for size? Create a Synonym for `Vector`, `Size`?

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but on this website it's customary to wait 24-48 hours before accepting. Accepting send a signal "I'm satisfied with this answer and I don't want any others." You really ought to give multiple people a chance to comment.

Comment: Ok. If you don't want.